# Getting and assigning values to Java arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, fibonacci

I'm currently learning Java and I've just beginned so my knowledge of it is not very good. 
I have a problem with a program I wrote that calculates the first 100 values of the  [Fibonacci sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci#Fibonacci_sequence). The point is that it just outputs the 2 and no other number.

This is the code of my program:

```
class MyClass1 {
public static void main(String[ ] args) {
  int[] fib = new int[102];
  fib[0] = 1;
  fib[1] = 1;
  int counter = 0;
  int n1, n2, fibSum;
  while(counter < (fib.length - 2)){
      n1 = fib[counter];
      System.out.println(fib[counter]);
      counter++;
      n2 = fib[counter];
      System.out.println(n2);
      counter++;
      fibSum = n1 + n2;
      System.out.println(fibSum);
      fib[counter] = fibSum;
      }

  }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some logical errors in your code.

First loop:-

Initially n1=fib[0]=1 and n2=fib[1]=1 and you print both. fib[2] is the sum and so it is 2. So far so good.

Second loop:-

n1 = fib[2] = 2. n2 = fib[3] = 0 and hence fib[4] = 2. This is where the problem happens. Hence you will always see 2 0 2 in the output from second loop onwards.

For Fibonacci sequence, you need to add the previous 2 values but you are only considering the previous value in your code. Here's a corrected version of your code:-

```
public static void main(String[ ] args) {
      double[] fib = new double[100];
      fib[0] = 1;
      fib[1] = 1;
      int counter = 2;
      double n1, n2, fibSum;
      System.out.println(fib[0]);
      System.out.println(fib[1]);
      while(counter < fib.length){
          n1 = fib[counter-1];
          n2 = fib[counter-2];
          fibSum = n1 + n2;
          System.out.println(fibSum);
          fib[counter] = fibSum;
          counter++;
      }
}
```

Note that I am using type double because type int or even long is not enough for going upto the 100th term in this sequence.

Answer (score 1):

[Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) is the sum of the previous 2 numbers:

`fibonacci(n) = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2)`

So it can be evaluated very nice using recursion:

```
private static long fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    else return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);     }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = 102;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        System.out.println(i + ": " + fibonacci(i));
}
```

Comment: And he tries to write down some interesting solution that works without recursion. And your answer misses to tell him why his solution doesnt work.

Comment: Yeah you are right probably. It may be just another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that

A) all array values are initialized to 0

B) you are accessing "the next" array value, before assigning a value to it!

When you change your outputs to:

```
  System.out.println("1. counter: " + counter + "/" + fib[counter]);
  counter++;
  n2 = fib[counter];
  System.out.println("2. counter: " + counter + "/" + fib[counter]);
  counter++;
  fibSum = n1 + n2;
  fib[counter] = fibSum;
  System.out.println("3. counter: " + counter + "/" + fib[counter]);
```

You will find that it prints:

```
1 counter: 0/1
2 counter: 1/1
3 counter: 2/2
1 counter: 2/2
2 counter: 3/0
```

The last row shows you what is going on: you fetch the value at index 3 ... before you assigned a value to it. Therefore your whole fibonacci sum ... doesn't "start"; because you keep loosing values.

In other words: you have to ensure that your counter increases properly:

```
while(counter < (fib.length - 2)){
  n1 = fib[counter];
  System.out.println("1 counter: " + counter + "/" + fib[counter]);
  n2 = fib[counter+1];
  System.out.println("2 counter: " + counter + "/" + fib[counter+1]);
  fibSum = n1 + n2;
  fib[counter+2] = fibSum;
  System.out.println("3 counter: " + counter + "/" + fib[counter+2]);
  counter++;
  }
```

Meaning: you need **one** full loop for each value of counter. When you run my solution, you will find that it works nicely (until counter hits 44/45 and we run into int overflow; as the numbers get too big).

Answer (score 0):

After your first iteration you'll have the following values:

n1 = 1

n2 = 1

fibsum = 2

fib[2] = 2

All other values from fib[3] to length are uninitialized.

So in the second iteration :

n1 = 2
now the counter value will be increased by 1 which is counter = 3

n2 = fib[3]
// this one in not calculated properly and hence the issue.